# Gtk+ 3 - Issues writing and autoscrolling in a TextView

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, pygobject

I have a `Gtk.ScrolledWindow()` with inside a `Gtk.TextView()`, (I'm using PyGObject introspection).

After I insert some text and autoscroll from another thread, calling several times in a row the method `append_text`, I get a couple of warnings then the GUI crashes.

This is the troublesome part of my code:

```
class TextViewWindow(Gtk.Window):

    [...]

    def append_text(self, text):
        self.textbuffer.insert(self.textbuffer.get_end_iter(), text)
        self.scroll_to_end()

    def scroll_to_end(self):
        self.textbuffer.place_cursor(self.textbuffer.get_end_iter())
        insert_mark = self.textbuffer.get_insert()
        self.textview.scroll_to_mark(insert_mark , 0.0, True, 0.0, 1.0)
```

**Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?**

--
Here are some of the errors that I got:

> Gtk-WARNING **: Invalid text buffer iterator: either the iterator is uninitialized, or the characters/pixbufs/widgets in the buffer have been modified since the iterator was created.
>   You must use marks, character numbers, or line numbers to preserve a position across buffer modifications.
>   You can apply tags and insert marks without invalidating your iterators,
>   but any mutation that affects 'indexable' buffer contents (contents that can be referred to by character offset)
>   will invalidate all outstanding iterators
>
> Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_index_to_pos: assertion `layout != NULL' failed
>
> Gtk-WARNING **: gtktextview.c:4813: somehow some text lines were modified or scrolling occurred since the last validation of lines on the screen - may be a text widget bug.
>
> Gtk:ERROR:gtktextview.c:4814:gtk_text_view_paint: code should not be reached

Comment: Are you appending the text in a separate thread?

Comment: I don't really know what that means, but I'm using threads. I'm redirecting logs to the GUI: there's a logger in the main worker with a `QueueHandler` then a `QueueListener` (started in `TextViewWindow.__init__`) has a custom handler call `append_text`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update [Gtk widgets from other threads](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-faq/stable/x481.html), you need to:

a. Call the following methods **before** you call `Gtk.main()`

```
GObject.threads_init()
Gdk.threads_init()
```

b. In your thread, surround the code that updates the Gtk widgets with:

```
Gdk.threads_enter()
# your code here
Gdk.threads_leave()
```

In your case, you'll probably need something like:

```
Gdk.threads_enter()
your_window.append_text('something')
your_window.scroll_to_end()
Gdk.threads_leave()
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But what's the difference between this approach and `GLib.idle_add` (suggested by @jcollado )? I looked around, but I did not understand when should I prefer one or the other.

Comment: The [`idle_add`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) means: when there is no high priority events in main thread, execute my code. This means that you have no sure when your code will be executed. When you use `threads_enter` and `threads_leave`, you acquire the lock of main thread and the code is executed right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using threads, as it seems from your comments, according to my experience, trying to update widgets in threads doesn't work well.

A workaround to this problem is schedule all the actions that update widgets using `GLib.idle_add` so that the update happens in the main thread.

Comment: Actually `GLib.idle_add` gave me some problem: `TypeError: Error invoking GLib.idle_add: Unexpected value for argument 'function'`, so I tried `GObject.idle_add` and it worked!! Do you know what's the difference?

Comment: I haven't found any difference. In fact, I tried `GObject.idle_add is GLib.idle_add` in a python shell and the value returned was `True`.

Comment: Awkward, to me it's `False`. Maybe mine are out of date, do you know how can I check the version number or update them?

Comment: You can get the version number looking at the `_version` attribute. In my case is 2.0 for both GLib and GObject. I always use the packaging tool in my linux distribution, so I haven't tried alternative ways to update those libraries.